# my while loop will not repeat the questions

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
    print('Welcome to Rangers Player Statistics')
    player_name = input('Which player would you like data on? (Kent, Defoe or Morelos)     ')
    player_stat = input('Which statistic would you like? (goals, shots or headers)      ')

    statistic_grab()

    new_stat = input('Would you like another stat?     ')
    while new_stat == 'yes':
        continue
    elif new_stat = 'no'
    print('Goodbye')
    break
else:
        print('Invalid Input')
```

2 things here, I am getting invalid syntax at my elif statement

what should I have where 'while true' to cause this to keep repeating itself unless the user says no

Comment: Welcome to SO! This has many syntax and indentation errors. Please go through and fix them before you can worry about your logic problem. `elif` needs a colon after it, its block needs to be indented 4 spaces, it's not possible to do an assignment inside an `elif`, final `else` needs to be indented 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while new_stat == 'yes':
    continue
```

This is a classic infinite loop. The `continue` here does not continue the outer loop; it continues this loop itself, which checks `new_stat == 'yes'` again, and keeps going because `new_stat` is still `'yes'`. There is nothing in this loop which could change `new_stat` to be something else, so the loop cannot terminate.

I believe, based on the logic of the `continue` and the `elif` you wrote afterwards, that this should be an `if` statement instead of a `while` loop:

```py
if new_stat == 'yes':
    continue
elif new_stat == 'no':
    print('Goodbye')
    break
```

There were a few other mistakes which are easy to fix; note the `==` instead of `=` to compare with `'no'`, the `:` at the end of the `elif` condition, and the indentation of `print` and `break` relative to the `elif`.

Comment: thanks for all the help and advice guys, new to this and the silly mistakes are made when playing about with the code to try and get it to work, ive currently got it working continually with while loop, that was before seeing i had response on here, still doesnt have full functionality though in places, i have an if statement inside a while loop but need to nearly run 2 loops one inside another as well as the if statement i think, is that possible? gonna have a play around here but thanks again guys.